# Find n largest elements from an array

Tags: c

I have an array

```
A[4]={4,5,9,1}
```

I need it would give the first 3 top elements like 9,5,4

I know how  to find the max element but how to find the 2nd and 3rd max?

i.e if

```
max=A[0]
for(i=1;i<4;i++)
{
  if (A[i]>max)
  {
    max=A[i];
    location=i+1;
  }
}
```

actually sorting will not be suitable for my application because,

the position number is also important for me i.e. I have to know in which positions the first 3 maximum is occurring, here it is in 0th,1th and 2nd position...so I am thinking of a logic

that after getting the max value if I could put 0 at that location and could apply the same steps for that new array i.e.{4,5,0,1}

But I am bit confused how to put my logic in code

Comment: 3 questions: Is it always about finding largest n numbers out of n + 1 numbers, or even 3 largest out of 4? Is it important to give the result in descending order? Is it out of question to manipulate the original array, or are we free to modify the array of numbers it points to?

Comment: Do you specifically need the top 3 or is 3 just an example and it may be any number of elements?

Comment: yes 3 is for example...it may be any number of elements...i have n number of elements in array from which I have to select m number of maximum elements along with their position number or index value

Comment: if m is a tiny fraction of n then I would go with a selection algorithm (someone posted an answer about it) if m is large then I would go with sorting. If you cant alter the elements position then duplicate the array keep a reference to the original position and sort that one

Answer (score 3):

Consider using the technique employed in the Python standard library.  It uses an underlying heap [data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29):

```
def nlargest(n, iterable):
    """Find the n largest elements in a dataset.

    Equivalent to:  sorted(iterable, reverse=True)[:n]
    """
    if n < 0:
        return []
    it = iter(iterable)
    result = list(islice(it, n))
    if not result:
        return result
    heapify(result)
    for elem in it:
        heappushpop(result, elem)
    result.sort(reverse=True)
    return result
```

The steps are:

1. Make an *n* length fixed array to hold the results.
2. Populate the array with the first *n* elements of the input.
3. Transform the array into a [minheap](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~tcortina/15-121sp10/Unit06B.pdf).
4. Loop over remaining inputs, replacing the top element of the heap if new data element is larger.
5. If needed, sort the final *n* elements.

The heap approach is memory efficient (not requiring more memory than the target output) and typically has a very low number of comparisons (see this [comparative analysis](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577573-compare-algorithms-for-heapqsmallest/)).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [selection algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm)

Also to mention that the complexity will be O(n) ie, O(n) for selection and O(n) for iterating, so the total is also O(n)

Comment: This is a decent approach (way better than sorting) but has some disadvantages:  1) two passes over the input data 2) significant auxiliary storage 3) need for care in pivot selection 4) run-time varies wildly depending on lucky or unlucky choice of the first pivots  and 5) it tends to use more comparisons than a single-pass algorithm using heaps.

Answer (score 0):

you can follw this procedure,
**1**. Add the n elements to another array `B[n]`;
**2**. Sort the array `B[n]`
**3**. Then for each element in `A[n...m]` check,
    `A[k]>B[0]`
   if so then number `A[k]` is among n large elements so,
   search for proper position for `A[k]` in `B[n]` and replace and move the numbers on left in `B[n]` so that `B[n]` contains `n` large elements.
**4**. Repeat this for all elements in `A[m]`.
At the end `B[n]` will have the n largest elements.

Answer (score -1):

What your essentially asking is equivalent to sorting your array in descending order. The fastest way to do this is using [heapsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort) or [quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) depending on the size of your array.

Once your array is sorted your largest number will be at index 0, your second largest will be at index 1, ...., in general your nth largest will be at index n-1

Comment: Sorting is the easiest way to do it, but also the most expensive in terms of total memory accesses and number of comparisons.